# SharePoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Want to be build an application (using SharePoint CSOM) to fetch all the Users and SharePoint Groups from a SharePoint Farm. The Users and Groups are required to be fetched from all the Site Collections which may be present on the farm. Having gone thru the documentation it appears that the Site class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site_methods(v=office.14).aspx represents only a 'single' SiteCollection. This is great. However, before the application can create the Site objects for each SiteCollection the app need to determine all the SiteCollections present on the farm. Is there a class / method to retrieve all the SiteCollection on a SharPoint farm?

Answer (score 2):

if the search is enabled, there is a way to do this by using search results:

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
            query.QueryText = string.Format("Path:{0} AND ContentClass:STS_Site", webAppURL);
            query.RowLimit = 500;//max row limit is 500 for KeywordQuery
            query.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
            query.EnableStemming = true;
            query.TrimDuplicates = false;
            query.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.PluggableAuthenticatedQuery;
            query.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
            SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor();
            ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = executor.ExecuteQuery(query);
            var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
            var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
```

Source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133073/get-all-site-collections-with-csom

(By the way, with SharePoint Online it is easier, you can use **SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable** class.
[SharePoint CSOM, retrieving site collections. Limited to 300?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405584/sharepoint-csom-retrieving-site-collections-limited-to-300/24406495#24406495))